# Rewritting url using mod_rewrite in .htacess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm figuring .htacess and it seems really powerful, but I'm in need of some guidance, could you give me a hand? In short, I got this url

```
https://www.example.org/details/foo/bar
```

I want to change it to

```
https://www.example.org/post/bar
```

But not as a redirect, just like an alias, to hide some url params in short.
How would I go? I tried quite a few different things but I'm having trouble figuring what to do, I thought it worked like

```
RewriteRule {old} {new}[R=301, F]
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: https://htaccess.xyz?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to redirect with 301 status, you can try:

```
RewriteRule ^details/foo/bar$ post/bar [L,R=301]
```

if you want the page to open in both urls, you can try:

```
RewriteRule ^post/bar$  details/foo/bar [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?post/bar$ /details/foo/bar [END]
```

It takes care to map requests to the "new" URI onto the "old" one, but still allows to use the "old" one. That to me appears what you ask by the term "alias".

You obviously need the rewriting module to be loaded and enabled in your http server. In general you should implement such rules in the actual http server's host configuration. If you do not have access to that you can use a distributed configuration file, but that comes with disadvantages. And again that feature needs to be enabled inside your http host (see the `AllowOverride` directive in the documentation for that).